# The event in jquery popup is triggered more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a survey application using Asp.net MVc. My events in jquery popup are triggered more than once. The more a popup is opened, the more it triggers in the event in the popup. What is the reason of this. Every time browsers are opened, the temporary javascript file that starts with the VM is removed. When the popup is closed, these opened virtual javascript files are not destroyed. What is the reason of this?

These events include adding rows to the table, updating and deleting rows.The AddOrEdit.cshtml file contains both screen components and javascript codes.

Images;

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

**AddOrEdit.cshtml(Jquery Popup)**

```
@using MerinosSurvey.Models
@model Questions
@{
 Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)", onreset = "return ResetForm(this)", id = "questionForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group row">
@Html.Label("QuestionId", "Soru No", new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-3" })
<div class="col-md-9">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QuestionId, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control", })

</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
@Html.Label("QuestionName", "Soru Adı", new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-3" })
<div class="col-md-9">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" 
} })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionName)
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsOtherOptionRequired, new { @class = "custom-control-input ", id = "IsOtherOptionRequired", })
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsOtherOptionRequired">Diğer Seçeneği Eklensin mi? 
</label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<hr class="style14">
<br>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Options)
<div class="table-wrapper form-group table-responsive-md">
<div class="table-title">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-9">Options</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-new" style="margin-bottom: 10px"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Option</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table optionTable">
<thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th style="display:none;" width="20%" scope="col">Seçenek Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Option Name</th>
        <th width="25%" scope="col">Update/Delete</th>
    </tr>

 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach (Options options in Model.Options)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;">@options.OptionId</td>
            <td>@options.OptionName</td>
            <td>
                <a class="add btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="fa fa-check">Approve</i>
                </a>
                <a class="edit btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil">Update</i>
                </a>
                <a class="delete btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash">Delete</i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-end">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px; color: black"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Kaydet</button> </div>
}
```

**Jquery add, edit, delete click events**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
//var actions = $("table.optionTable td:last-child").html();

var actions =
' <a class="add btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-check">Onayla</i></a>' +
    '<a class="edit btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pencil">Güncelle</i></a>' +
    '<a class="delete btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-trash">Sil</i></a>';

  // Append table with add row form on add new button click
 $(".add-new").click(function () { //RUNS MULTIPLE TIMES ON CHROME
   debugger;
   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $(".btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   var index = $("table.optionTable tbody tr:last-child").index();
   var row = '<tr>' +
    '<td style="display:none;">0</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="optionName" id="optionName"></td>' +
    '<td>' +
    actions +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $("table.optionTable").append(row);
  $("table.optionTable tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});


 // Add row on add button click
 $(".add").click(function () { //RUNS MULTIPLE TIMES ON CHROME
   debugger;
   var empty = false;
   var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
   input.each(function () {
    if (!$(this).val().trim()) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        empty = true;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
});
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
  if (!empty) {
    input.each(function () {
        $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val().trim());
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
    $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");

  }
});

// Edit row on edit button click
$(".edit").click(function () { //RUNS MULTIPLE TIMES ON CHROME
  debugger;
  /*td: nth - child(2)*/
  //$(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
  $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:first-child, :last-child)").each(function () {
    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
});
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
  $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(".btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});


// Delete row on delete button click
$(".delete").click(function () {//RUNS MULTIPLE TIMES ON CHROME
  debugger;
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");

  var rowCount = $('table.optionTable tbody tr').length;
  if (rowCount > 0) {
      $(".btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
      $(".btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }

  });
});
```

Comment: Please make sure your posted code is a [mcve]. Parsing 100+ lines of code is going to prevent people helping.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are right. I have editted my question.Could you help me?

Comment: Which line of code from the above is getting called mutiple times>? Can you please point out specifically

Comment: @NanditaSharma all events are triggered multiple time. For example, once you open the popup once, there is no problem. If you close and reopen, all events run 2 times. After closing and opening for the third time, all events run 3 times. In other words, the browser opens the javascript code in AddOrEdit.cshtml as a page like VM6121 every popup. As you see it on image

Comment: Try changing youe event bindings like this $(".delete").off('click').on('click', function () {})    This will first unbind the click event earlier linked on the popup and bind a new click handler

Comment: Should I use $ (document) .ready (function () {})?

Comment: I do not work with asp.net, so I am not sure why a new JS code is inserted in DOM everytime you are opening a pop up. What I suggested you is just a fail safe that I think should work for you. May be someone with better knowlege of both asp and js can guide you better

Comment: The add-new button outside the table worked. But .add, .edit, .delet in the table do not react.

Comment: Are you saying that the javascript code should be in an external file.

Comment: Try this way $(document).off("click").on( "click", ".delete", function() {
// Your code here
})

Comment: As per me, JS code should only load one time. From whats happening in your code, it seems new JS is being inserted in DOM on every pop up opening

Comment: I'm going to try adding it into the parent screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are binding event multiple time by using class selector. It means After adding new DOM in the document, bind a click event on newly added action buttons, but it is binding click event on existing action buttons also.

So simple tick to solve your problem is you have to unbind existing click event and bind new once.

```
$(".add-new").unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
    //your code here
});
$(".add").unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
    //your code here
});
$(".edit").unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
    //your code here
});
$(".delete").unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **on/off** methods to handle this.

```
$(".add-new").off('click').on('click', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open popup for the second time I believe running $(".add-new").length will return  2 for you. Try to resolve that first which will automatically resolve your events problem.

Do changes such that $(".add-new").length is always 1